# Error: no encuentra columna en relación polimórfica, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Hace unos días hice una pregunta acá pero me dijeron que eso no era un "problema" porque era de opiniones que no me podían ayudar, que lo pusiera en el chat, lo hice y nada, nadie respondió, así que hoy vengo con un error a ver si me ayudan.

Tengo la tabla Perfiles

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('web');
        $table->integer('status');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unique();

        // Foreing Keys
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

La tabla Categorías

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->integer('status');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Y la tabla Profesiones

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('professions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->integer('status');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Antes que nada, el perfil no es la típica tabla de perfiles de usuario, es donde el usuario creará su perfil profesional.

Ya que un perfil puede pertenecer a una categoría (1:1) (Desarrollador Web a la Categoría Informática) y una categoría puede tener muchas profesiones (1:n) (La Categoría Informática puede tener, desarrolladores, diseñadores, técnicos, analistas...) consideré hacer una tabla y relación polimórfica para dicho fin.

Tabla polimórfica categoriables

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categoriables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('categoriable_id');
        $table->string('categoriable_type');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');

        // Foreing Keys
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Ahora, al momento de relacionar lo hago así:
Modelo Category

```
// Relacion 1:n Profile polimorfica
public function categoriable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}

// Relacion n:n Professions polimorfica
public function profesions(){
    return $this->morphedByMany(Profession::class, 'categoriable');
}
```

Modelo Profile

```
// Relacion 1:1 Users
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

// Relacion 1:1 Category polimorfica
public function category(){
    return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'categoriable');
}
```

Modelo Profession

```
// Relacion 1:n Category polimorfica
public function category(){
    return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'categoriable');
}
```

Si en tinker hago:

```
Use App\Models\Profile;
$pro = Profile::find(1);
$pro->category;
```

Me da este error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.categoriable_type' in 'where
> clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`categoriable_type` = App\Models\Profile and `categories`.`categoriable_i d` = 1 and `categories`.`categoriable_id` is not null limit 1).

Si hago:

```
Use App\Models\Category;
$cat = Category::find(1);
$cat->profesions;
```

Ahí si que recupero las profesiones bien, osea que esa relación esta buena.

```
 App\Models\Profession {#3922
    id: 1,
    name: "Web Developer",
    slug: "web-developer",
    status: 1,
    created_at: "2022-11-30 14:17:17",
    updated_at: "2022-11-30 14:17:17",
    pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot {#4868
      category_id: 1,
      categoriable_id: 1,
      categoriable_type: "App\Models\Profession",
    },
  },
  App\Models\Profession {#4870
    id: 5,
    name: "Analista de Datos",
    slug: "analista",
    status: 1,
    created_at: "2022-11-30 14:17:17",
    updated_at: "2022-11-30 14:17:17",
    pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot {#4869
      category_id: 1,
      categoriable_id: 5,
      categoriable_type: "App\Models\Profession",
    },
  },
```

Pero si intento a la inversa desde Profesiones:

```
Use App\Models\Profession;
$profe = Profession::find(1);
$profe->category;
```

Me da el mismo error:

> 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.categoriable_type' in 'where
clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`categoriable_type` = App\Models\Profession and `categories`.`categoriabl e_id` = 1 and `categories`.`categoriable_id` is not null limit 1).

Se que el problema es que no he puesto bien el tipo de relación (morph) pero es que ya probé de muchas formas y no logro dar con que tipo de relación debo poner. Ya hice 3 cursos de Laravel y claro los proyectos salieron bien porque seguí los pasos pero en este proyecto que quiero hacer desde cero no se me da.

Espero hoy si cumpla con la opción de que esto sea un problema. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te explico paso a paso.

-Las tablas Perfiles, Categorías y Profesiones están bien.
-La tabla **categoriables** la puedes optimizar, en vez de crear tu los campos **ables** deja que Laravel los cree por ti de la siguiente manera

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categoriables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        /*$table->unsignedBigInteger('categoriable_id');
        $table->string('categoriable_type');*/
        $table->morphs('categoriable');

        $table->timestamps();

        // Foreing Keys
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

Modelo Category

```
// Esto se evita haciéndolo en la Migración. Ya explicado antes.
/*public function categoriable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}*/

// n:n Profile >> Una Categoría puede tener o "Pertenece a" muchos Perfiles con la funcion categoriable (son los campos que llevan esa palabra clave)
public function profiles(){
    // Esto es un belongsToMany "polimorfico", esta es la tabla madre y solo funciona para n:n
    return $this->morphedByMany(Profile::class, 'categoriable');
}

// n:n Profesion >> Una Categoría puede tener o "Pertenece a" muchas Profesiones con la funcion categoriable
public function profesions(){
    // Esto es un belongsToMany "polimorfico", esta es la tabla madre y solo funciona para n:n
    return $this->morphedByMany(Profession::class, 'categoriable');
}
```

Modelo Profile

```
// Relacion 1:1 Users
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

// n:n Category >> Un Perfil puede tener o "Pertenece a" muchas Categorias con la función categoriable
public function category(){
    // Esto es un belongsToMany "polimorfico"
    /* No puede ser morphOne porque Category esta configurada para n:n */
    return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'categoriable');
}
```

Modelo Profession

```
// n:n Category >> Una Profesion puede tener o "Pertenece a" muchas Categorias con la función categoriable
public function categories(){
    // Esto es un belongsToMany "polimorfico"
    /* Igual que en Profile, no puede ser morphOne porque Category esta configurada para n:n */
    return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'categoriable');
```

Te dejo una tabla que yo uso para saber mejor como hacer las relaciones, y puedes obtener mas info en la [Documentación Oficial de Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

```
hasOne          > 1:1       > Tiene Uno
hasMany         > 1:n       > Tiene Muchos
hasManyThrough  > 1:n       > Tiene Muchos a traves de
belongsTo       > 1:1       > Pertenece a
belongsToMany   > n:n       > Pertenece y tiene Muchos
hasOneThrough   > 1:1       > Tiene Uno a traves de
morphTo         > 1:1 y 1:n > Definir Tabla Polimorfica
morphedByMany   > nn        > Definir Tabla Polimorfica
morphOne        > 1:1       > Tiene Uno Polimorfica
morphMany       > 1:n       > Tiene Muchos Polimorfica
morphToMany     > n:n       > Tiene Muchos Polimorfica
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfectamente y la tabla es una ayuda excepcional.