# ¿Tengo algun problema con la relacion mucho a muchos en laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Estoy creando un sistema de matriculas y necesito crear una relacion de alumno a padre luego de su formulario por separado, el punto es que ya segui todos los pasos para crear la relación pero cuando ambos se crean, en la tabla pivote no se crean las relaciones:
Aqui el modelo de padre y alumno:

```
  public function padres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Padre::class,'alumno_padre','padre_id','alumno_id');
    }

public function alumnos()
```

{
return $this->belongsToMany(Alumno::class, 'alumno_padre','alumno_id','padre_id');
}
Aqui mi metodo create y store del PadreController:

```
 public function createdatospadre()
  {
    $alumno = new Alumno();
     // Recibe el identificador del alumno si viene como parámetro en la URL
     $alumno_id = request()->input('alumno_id');
    return view('secretaria.matricula.datospadre',compact('alumno_id','alumno'));
  }
$padre = Padre::create(
    array_merge(
        $request->only('primernombre', 'segundonombre', 'primerapellido', 'segundoapellido',
        'numerodeidentidad','telefonopersonal', 'lugardetrabajo', 'oficio', 'telefonooficina', 'ingresos' ),
        ['tipo' => 'Padre']
    )
);


$alumno_id = $request->input('alumno_id');
if ($alumno_id) {
    // Buscar al alumno correspondiente
    $alumno = Alumno::find($alumno_id);

    // Relacionar al padre con el alumno
    $alumno->padre()->attach($padre->id);
}

return redirect('/alumnomadre');
```

}

y mi vista:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="alumno_id" value="{{ request()->input('alumno_id') }}">


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{{ route('datosmadre.create', ['alumno_id' => $alumno->id]) }}">Agregar Madre</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Luego del formulario de padre.

Comment: Yo tuve un problema con las relaciones y esta pregunta me ayudó: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/571399/error-no-encuentra-columna-en-relaci%c3%b3n-polim%c3%b3rfica-laravel

Comment: Lo que veo es que a la función de la relación la llamaste `padres`  pero luego usas `$alumno->padre()->attach($padre->id)`